# Prevent temporarily recycling with item renderers

Tags: apache-flex, recycle

I'm looking for a way to keep unrecycled state on item renderer time to play animation ?

My problem is my animation is played well but if there is another data changed in my datagrid, my item renderer is recycled to play the new animation so the first animation is stopped. I just would like in this case to instantiate 2 item renderers and let the time to the first animation to finish.

How can I do that please ?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear to me. Does my answer to your previous question also fix this issue, or do you really want to queue up the animations?

Comment: Your previous answer fix my issue thank you again, I was just "lost in my code" after some unecessary modifications....